# Getting AWS Root Certificates for IoT Core Thing

Tags: amazon-web-services, openssl, certificate, aws-iot, ca

In **AWS IoT Core** I created a **thing**, created a **Policy** for the thing, created a **Certificate** for the thing and attached the Policy to the Certificate.

After that I downloaded the ***.crt*** and the **.key** files of the Certificate I verified if they match with the following command:

`(openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in certificate.pem.crt | openssl md5 ; openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in private.pem.key | openssl md5) | uniq`

and got a single hash back, which indicates that they match

`(stdin)= 97c1a8816c35acbfgt04f325aeacae6`

The only thing left was to find the **Root CA** that my thing Certificate was signed with.

I found the AWS developer guide for the server certs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/server-authentication.html#server-authentication-certs) and I downloaded the **VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary G5 root CA certificate**, which I renamed to **rootCA.pem**.

But when I ran a test to verify the CA with the following command:

`openssl s_client -connect <my ID>.iot.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com:8443 /
-CAfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/rootCA.pem /
-cert /etc/mosquitto/certs/certificate.pem.crt /
-key /etc/mosquitto/certs/private.pem.key`

I get this response with the error **unable to get local issuer certificate** (see below)

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=1 C = US, O = Symantec Corporation, OU = Symantec Trust Network, CN = Symantec Class 3 ECC 256 bit SSL CA - G2
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=Washington/L=Seattle/O=Amazon.com, Inc./CN=*.iot.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com
   i:/C=US/O=Symantec Corporation/OU=Symantec Trust Network/CN=Symantec Class 3 ECC 256 bit SSL CA - G2
 1 s:/C=US/O=Symantec Corporation/OU=Symantec Trust Network/CN=Symantec Class 3 ECC 256 bit SSL CA - G2
   i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDlTCCAzygAwIBAgIQGw ...
——END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=US/ST=Washington/L=Seattle/O=Amazon.com, Inc./CN=*.iot.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com
issuer=/C=US/O=Symantec Corporation/OU=Symantec Trust Network/CN=Symantec Class 3 ECC 256 bit SSL CA - G2
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Client Certificate Types: RSA sign, DSA sign, ECDSA sign
Requested Signature Algorithms: ECDSA+SHA512:RSA+SHA512:ECDSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA256:DSA+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA224:RSA+SHA224:DSA+SHA224:ECDSA+SHA1:RSA+SHA1:DSA+SHA1
Shared Requested Signature Algorithms: ECDSA+SHA512:RSA+SHA512:ECDSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA256:DSA+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA224:RSA+SHA224:DSA+SHA224:ECDSA+SHA1:RSA+SHA1:DSA+SHA1
Peer signing digest: SHA512
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 2398 bytes and written 1448 bytes
Verification error: unable to get local issuer certificate
---
New, TLSv1.2, Cipher is ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 256 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: EB3B32C8 …
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 783A17EB6 …
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1587558792
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
    Extended master secret: yes
---
```

Does someone know how to get the **Root CA** for my **thing** Certificate?

Thanks

---

## Edit:

Thanks to [Ben T's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1373856/ben-t) advice I created a new **thing** in the **Mumbai Region**. Surprisingly I can see an option now to download the **root certificate** directly from the Certificate creation screen (see below)

[image]

After running `openssl s_client -connect` again with the new certs/key I finally get `verify return:1`.

**AWESOME**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Verisign certificate is used for legacy endpoints.

You should use the newer certificates for the Amazon Trust Services endpoints. e.g. the one at https://www.amazontrust.com/repository/AmazonRootCA1.pem

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/server-authentication.html#server-authentication-certs

> All new AWS IoT Core regions, beginning with the May 9, 2018 launch of AWS IoT Core in the Asia Pacific (Mumbai) Region, serve only ATS certificates.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. So the `AmazonRootCA1.pem` would not work for the `ap-southeast-2` region?

Comment: Btw, I get the same error with the **AmazonRootCA1.pem**.

Comment: For `ap-southeast-2` you probably need to create an ATS endpoint and use that. It should be in the form `prefix-ats.iot.region.amazonaws.com`  See https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/iot/aws-iot-core-ats-endpoints/